# SDL2 is not seeing X11/Video Device correctly

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl, x11

(I am aware there is a great deal of documentation on the subject, but I am either too inexperienced to find the one that works or I have a different problem than the one documented)

I am trying to load up a simple SDL wrapper that I wrote on my Mac on Linux (Lubuntu 20.04, LXQt 0.14.1). However when `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` is called, the following `SDL_Error()` return statement is generated: `No available video device`. I have verified that my `DISPLAY` envvar is set to `:0` (which is correct according to `xterm`) and my `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` is unset.

Setting my `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` to x11 triggers this alternative error on init `x11 not available`.

I am rather stumped, the only possible conclusion I could draw from this is that I am somehow not using x11 or am going about this wrong.

Here is a minimal example that triggers this error:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());
}
```

I really appreciate any help I can get!

I am using the `libsdl2-dev` apt package for SDL2

Comment: What did SDL_Init return?

Comment: @user253751 -1 in all cases

Comment: @TTG are you running it from the same xterm that reports `DISPLAY`, and that you can launch e.g. `glxinfo` or other `xterm` from? Or is is separate shell (e.g. virtual tty on ctrl-alt-f1 or remote ssh session) that have no connection to your x11 server? Are you sure you're running x11 and not e.g. wayland (`ps aux|grep X`)?

Comment: @keltar It is X11 as the xorg process is running. I am running from the correct terminal yes and am on a local machine(not ssh or whatelse)

Comment: @TTG so you can launch second `xterm` from your terminal but not your test program? That's weird. What's the output of `ldd ./your_program`? Do any other SDL2 program works (e.g. supertux2)? Could you build SDL yourself and try it with that, preferably with debugging symbols enabled?

Comment: @keltar I'll try ldd. And yes SDL works eith Unreal Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had forgotten to link X11 during compilation which caused SDL_VIDEO to fail to initialise. This was resolved by using -lX11.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: As per the date of this comment, there is no need to link to X11 everything should be dynamically linked during the runtime of configuration [`../configure`]{https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Installation}