# SDL 'no available video device' error and not detecting x11

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl, x11, sdl-2

I'm having a similar problem to that listed here - [SDL2 is not seeing X11/Video Device correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103555/sdl2-is-not-seeing-x11-video-device-correctly)

I'm trying to follow the Lazy Foo tutorial for SDL and I keep getting the 'no available video device' error. If I update `SDL_VIDEODRIVER` to x11 I get that x11 is not available. I'm linking against it but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm calling `SDL_GetVideoDriver` at the beginning of my program and all it's seeing is `dummy`.

System is Ubuntu 20.04.

If anyone has any tips on how to try and debug this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile SDL2 yourself or did you use the one from the package manager?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem turned out to be that I had compiled SDL2 myself instead of using a package manager, but I had also then installed it with a package manager. It was using the version from my compilation which didn't include the drivers correctly.

The easiest solution was just to remove the compiled installation and go with the package manager.